# Problem with CCSpriteFrameCache and sprite textures

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I have recently switched from using separate resource files to using a texture atlas. I experimented with replacing a few `[CCSprite spriteWithFile]` with `[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName]`. This works fine except one thing. The CCSprite's texture dimensions are incorrect. Here is my code :

```
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
CCSprite * leftArrow = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"smallLeftArrow.png"];
CGSize arrowSize = [leftArrow texture].contentSizeInPixels;
CCSprite * selectedLA = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"smallLeftArrow.png"];
selectedLA.opacity = 100;
CCMenuItem * leftArrowItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:leftArrow selectedSprite:selectedLA target:[HelloWorldLayer sharedHelloWorldLayer] selector:@selector(doLeft)];
leftArrowItem.position = ccp(- arrowSize.width, arrowSize.height);
CCLOG(@"arrow.width = %f arrow.height %f",arrowSize.width, arrowSize.height);
```

This is the output on the debugger:

```
2011-08-29 18:27:04.239 Zero Gravity Combat[454:307] arrow.width = 1024.000000 arrow.height 1024.000000
```

The size of the entire texture atlas is 1024 X 1024. I am using texture packer to create the texture atlas. Is there a way to fix this or do I need to create a texture manually to determine dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously want to get the size of the arrow sprite. Thats simple: `leftArrow.contentSize`.

What you've done is getting the size of the used texture, which is of size 1024x1024. The size of the texture is not always the same size as the sprite's size.